# Counting objects in binary raster image in R

Tags: r, object-detection, raster, edge-detection

I have a raster:

```
r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
set.seed(0)
values(r) <- runif(ncell(r))
```

[image: img1]

From the raster I select the top 10% and change to binary:

```
r_10<-r[[1]]>=quantile(r,.90)
```

[image: img2]

From this subset raster `r_10` all green pixels have the same value of 1. I would like to change these values, by identifying pixels or groups of pixels as objects and labeling every new object with a new ID. The new raster should have values like this example image:
[image: img3]

Some objects can have multiple pixels, and they all should have the same object ID (like number 8).

How can I code this up in R? I thought to use some sort of edge detection, or Sobel filter, but cant figure it out.

Here is a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49653146/counting-objects-in-binary-images), not the same, but its in python, and I need to implement this in R.

Any alternative solutions are welcome.

Comment: what does it mean by "objects"? All these green pixels have value of 1. When you label them, does the order matter? For example, can the number 1 be assigned to the bottom pixel instead of the top-left one?

Comment: I use the term "object" very loosely. Here, I just want to reclassify groups of neighboring pixels to different values. The order of labeling them does not matter. As long as very "object" has its own unique ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure there are multiple ways to answer this questions (computer vision and GIS). Here is an GIS solution (found [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/279264/165082)) to the problem at hand:

```
# Create raster data
r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
set.seed(0)
values(r) <- runif(ncell(r))

# Select top 10% of highest values and convert to binary
r_10<-r[[1]]>=quantile(r,.90)
r_10[r_10==0]<-NA

# Vectorize
Vector_r_10<-rasterToPolygons(r_10)
plot(Vector_r_10)

# Add new Obj_ID class
Vector_r_10$Obj_ID<-1:nrow(Vector_r_10)

# Identify neighboring pixels
nb<-poly2nb(Vector_r_10)

# Create regions
create_regions <- function(data) {
  group <- rep(NA, length(data))
  group_val <- 0
  while(NA %in% group) {
    index <- min(which(is.na(group)))
    nb <- unlist(data[index])
    nb_value <- group[nb]
    is_na <- is.na(nb_value)
    if(sum(!is_na) != 0){
      prev_group <- nb_value[!is_na][1]
      group[index] <- prev_group
      group[nb[is_na]] <- prev_group
    } else {
      group_val <- group_val + 1
      group[index] <- group_val
      group[nb] <- group_val
    }
  }
  group
}
region<-create_regions(nb)

# Union on new regions
pol_rgn<-spCbind(Vector_r_10,region)
New_Vector_r_10<-unionSpatialPolygons(pol_rgn,region)
New_Vector_r_10<-as(New_Vector_r_10,"SpatialPolygonsDataFrame")
plot(New_Vector_r_10)
```

This is a shapefile now, but for my purpose its fine. One can always convert this back to raster as well.

Comment: One can edit the ```snap``` parameter in the ```poly2nb``` to select neighbors at appropriate distances.